# How to flatten an SQL join with collection using LINQ query?

Tags: c#, linq, linq-to-sql, linq-to-entities

Let's say I have two tables: Users and UserRoles:

```
Users:
+----+
| Id |
+----+
|  1 |
|  2 |
|  3 |
+----+

UserRoles:
+--------+----------+
| UserId | Name     |
+--------+----------+
|      1 | A        |
|      1 | B        |
|      2 | A        |
|      3 | C        |
+--------+----------+
```

I need to be able to select above data into a list of User objects that looks like this:

```
class User
{
   public int Id { get; set; }
   public List<string> Roles { get; set; }
}
```

The best I could come up with is the following, but it ends up generating a nested select statement, and I don't know if that's going to hurt performance:

```
List<Device> usersWithRoles = from user in Users
   select new Device
   {
      Id = user.Id,
      Roles = (from role in UserRoles where role.UserId == user.Id select role.Name).ToList()
   }.ToList();
```

Is there a better (more performant way) to accomplish this?  For example with join, I was thinking something like this, but don't know how to populate roles from the join:

```
List<Device> usersWithRoles = from user in Users
   join user_role in UserRoles on user.Id equals user_role.UserId
   select new Device
   {
      Id = user.Id,
      Roles = ??? // how do I populate this
   }.ToList();
```

Thanks.

Comment: Are you using EF? If that's the case you should create a relation between a User and its associated Roles via the UserRole relation. This is a fundamental part of EF which it handles with ease, so you don't have to deal with complex grouping or joining logic.

Comment: @silkfire I am using EF.  The problem is there are a bunch of legacy tables without foreign key definitions, and DB cannot be touched.  Also, this is just a small part of a bigger query.  I'm assuming you suggest I can do something like Roles = user.Roles using navigation properties?

Comment: That's right. So you don't have access to the database itself? I'd try to do it with classic SQL + LINQ in your data layer.

Comment: In LINQ to SQL, a `GroupJoin` can be created by using `into` on the `join`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `GroupJoin` LINQ to SQL method:

```
List<Device> usersWithRoles = from user in Users
   join user_role in UserRoles on user.Id equals user_role.UserId into roles
   select new Device
   {
      Id = user.Id,
      Roles = roles.ToList()
   }.ToList();
```

Comment: Pretty cool, 'into' was the piece I was missing (although I still had to call 'ToList()', on roles when assigning it to Roles).

Comment: @Eternal21 Sorry, yes that is because of the type of `Roles` in the class.